# ELF, Compiler: Elf file(Shared library) convert to basic block?

Tags: compiler-construction, elf

I know elf file possible to dump using objdump.

but i don't know dump file convert to so file.

Is it possible?

Finally i want to obfuscation in so file. so i guess follow step.

1.Generate basic block in so file.

2.Obfuscation to basic block.

3.Remake so file.

Is this possible step?

Comment: I don't think ELF files have any information about basic blocks. This information isn't needed for execution or debugging and there's no reason to save it in the output.

Comment: Your question is exceedingly unclear, but the most likely answer is "no, it's not possible".